# ClickOnce - Is there a NoRebuild Property or switch?

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

Is there a way to JUST PUBLISH what is already IN the bin folder to app-publish?

I don't want an entire rebuild, i just want to publish what's there

Microsoft MUST have been smart enough to include some switch to handle this when we are using msbuild.exe to launch a publish?

I don't seem to be able to find one...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the build starts, but exits if there are no changes, so all is good!